Bottleneck using np.where (in term of computing ressources i.e. memory and speed)
In the current example, I spent (many) hours in order to find a way to sort the M matrix so that it corresponds exactly to the target one.

The 2 first columns are used to reorganize M
The matrixOrder indicates how to "proceed" (couples of values are important)
note the 2 couples [5, 15] and [5, 11] which must be tackled differently
at the final stage, the third column is extracted

For big arrays (hundreds thousands of lines, even millions), the amount of memory is huge and this step time is consuming (bottleneck).
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np

M = np.array([ [ 5  , 15 , 6 ],
               [ 14 , 15 , 14 ],
               [ 5  , 11 , 350 ],
               [ 5  , 11, 352 ],
               [ 5  , 11 , 351 ],
               [ 5  , 11 , 350 ],
               [ 9  , 11 , 351 ],
               [ 9  , 11 , 95 ],
               [ 9  , 11 , 353 ],
               [ 9  , 11 , 354 ],
               [ 28 , 15 , 28 ],
               [ 2  , 8 , 46 ],
               [ 2  , 8 , 353 ],
               [ 2  , 8 , 45 ],
               [ 21 , 15 , 21 ],
               [ 31 , 20 , 355 ],
               [ 31 , 20 , 358 ]])


matrixOrder = np.array([ [14, 15],
                         [2 , 8],
                         [31, 20],
                         [5 , 11],
                         [21, 15],
                         [9, 11],
                         [5, 15],
                         [28, 15] ])
                                           
Target = np.array([ [ 14 , 15 , 14 ],
                    [ 2 , 8 , 46 ],
                    [ 2 , 8 , 353 ],
                    [ 2 , 8 , 45 ],
                    [ 31 , 20 , 355 ],
                    [ 31 , 20 , 358 ],
                    [ 5 , 11 , 350 ],
                    [ 5 , 11 , 352 ],
                    [ 5 , 11 , 351 ],
                    [ 5 , 11 , 350 ],
                    [ 21 , 15 , 21 ],
                    [ 9 , 11 , 351 ],
                    [ 9 , 11 , 95 ],
                    [ 9 , 11 , 353 ],
                    [ 9 , 11 , 354 ],
                    [ 5 , 15 , 6 ],
                    [ 28 , 15 , 28 ] ])
                                        
index = np.where( (matrixOrder[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1) == M[:, 0].tolist()) &
                  (matrixOrder[:, 1].reshape(-1, 1) == M[:, 1].tolist()) )

T = M[index[1], :]
check = np.array_equal(Target, T)


well firstly, you can remove .tolist()

Try doing a dictionary lookup instead of using np.where
something like -
def sort_mat(M, ord):
    # Convert order pairs to tuples
    k = [tuple(r) for r in ord]
    
    # Make lookup dictionary
    d = {k: i for i,k in enumerate(k)}
    
    # Get sorted indices
    idx = sorted(range(len(M)), key=lambda x: d.get((M[x,0], 
    M[x,1]), len(k)))
    
    #return the sorted matrix
    return M[idx]


Many thanks for this solution. This is not trivial and i had to spend some time to analyse it but i figure out how it works, but it's fine now.  For sure it'll be usefull in a next future :-)
